# How to handle image not found method in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a condition where if the image is not found, it will no longer return the image

Comment: plz add some bare minimum reproducible code

Comment: Using this https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: Can you add some code with your question?
Where do you want to get the image and which source do you want to use?
like from assets or from network?